Migrating grafana-loki data from binary installation to kubernetes installation
I currently have a Loki installation done using the Loki binary download and running as a service on a VM.
I am creating a Kubernetes cluster for the monitoring tools we use today (Loki, Grafana, Prometheus, AlertManager).
How do I migrate the logs present in the current Loki to the one that will run on the K8S cluster?
this is the current loki storage configuration block:
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h

I haven't tried this migration yet but I had problems migrating from one installation to another using binaries with different versions, I couldn't migrate the stored logs.
